# Ошибка в коде. Код не запускается

Tags: python

Мой код:

```
async def greatSender():
    client.get_channel(id=846658613186527233)
    await channel.send(input('message:'))
```

Вылазит ошибка:

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 100, in on_ready
    await greatSender()
  File "main.py", line 95, in greatSender
    await channel.send(input('message:'))
NameError: name 'channel' is not defined
```

Comment: Из-за каждой мелкой ошибки будешь вопрос создавать? Если не научишься читать ошибки, и хотя бы гуглить, что они означают, то долго будешь со своим ботом возиться...

Answer (score 1):

Ну по смыслу кода видимо надо присвоить получаемое значение в эту переменную:

```
async def greatSender():
    channel = client.get_channel(id=846658613186527233)
    await channel.send(input('message:'))
```

Comment: Видимо да, причем в одном из предыдущих вопросов `channel =` есть: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303110/1365 , но в процессе "исправления" он почему-то потерялся.

Comment: @insolor Ну, я понимаю, что тут всё печально у топик стартера с собранностью, но что ж делать )